# Find the smallest $t$ such that the object reaches the height of $96\text{ feet}$ at time $t$.

Tags: classical-mechanics

> An object is tossing upwards with an initial speed of $64 \text{ feet/sec}$.Suppose the gravitational acceleration is $32\text{ feet/sec}^2$. Find the smallest $t$ such that the object reaches the height of $96\text{ feet}$ at time $t$.

My problem: Which formula I have to use to find $t$?

Thanks.

Comment: It seems like object will never reach $96$ feet.

Comment: @Jihad But what is the formula to solve such problem?$s=v_0+(1/2)gt^2$?

Comment: $S = S_0 + v_0t + \frac{gt^2}{2}$

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski what is $S_0$?

Comment: @Flip Starting space coordinate, in your case an object is on a ground level, so $S_0 = 0$.

Comment: Of course, you should consider the sign of $g$, a correct form should be vector-wise: $S = \vec{v_0}t + \frac{\vec{g}t^2}{2}$

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski here I have to use $g=-32ft/sec^2$ or $g=32ft/sec^2$

Comment: @Flip As $v_0$ is directed opposite to $g$, you should use $g = -32 ft/sec^2$

Answer (score 0):

We have
$$ s = ut + \frac{1}{2}at^2 $$

which we can rearrange to get
$$ t^2 + 2 \dfrac{2u}{a} - 2 \dfrac{s}{a} = 0 $$
and applying the quadratic equation to that (with correct values of s, u, and a) should get you your answer!